# Sending email from Django contact form on Google App Engine redirects to 404

Tags: django, google-app-engine, nginx, google-cloud-platform

I've been trying to set up a django contact form on a simple blogging application which is currently hosted on Google cloud platform.
The app seems to work locally, it sends an email out and redirects the end user to a completed page, however when I push it to the production server it tries to send an email for around 30s then times out and I get redirected to a 404. 
I've checked my nginx error and access logs as well as my gunicorn log and it seems that a gunicorn worker times out after 30 seconds, hence the 404. Initially I thought that this happens because my port 587 is locked on Google cloud network however even when I'm opening said port it still fails.

My settings.py:

```
Emailer EMAIL_HOST = "send.one.com" 
EMAIL_PORT = "587"
EMAIL_HOST_USER = "postman@email.co.uk"       
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = "password"
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = "postman@email.co.uk" 
SERVER_EMAIL = "postman@email.co.uk"
```

I've tried to run it through TLS by using 
   EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
But no success.
Has anyone encountered this problem before?

Comment: Is the `Emailer` the typo or you join the previous line of comment accidentally?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

App Engine blocks this kind of connection which opens socket.

You have 2 options if you want to send mails on Google App Engine:

1. Directly use Mail API provided by Google App Engine, it will be a set of API that handles mailing on Google App Engine, for reference you can look here: [Google App Engine Mail API for Python](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/mail/)
2. Use Django wrapper for GAE Mail API, like the one built in in `rocket_engine` or standalone one.

   - [rocket engine](https://github.com/xando/django-rocket-engine)
   - [standalone email backend for Django on GAE](https://github.com/littleq0903/appengine_emailbackend)

If you're doing this you can perform email sending in the same way of what Django does, it's more like a plugin could be installed into your Django project, then your settings will work without any change.

Comment: To answer your comment, it was a typo sorry! Also I've re-read the documentation on GAE and figured out that I'd need to use their GAE's API in order to be able to send the emails out. Thanks for your help though, I've forgotten to update the question. :)